# How to access Roles of a QAbstractListModel used in a QML ComboBox via Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, combobox, qml, qt5.4

I have a model based on `QAbstractListModel`.

It implements several different roles to provide various pieces of data.

I've set the `model` as well as the `textRole` inside a `ComboBox`. This perfectly works.

When the user selects an item (row) from this `ComboBox`, I need to run some Javascript that reads that `Item`'s values for several different roles and uses them to do useful work.

However, I cannot find any way to do that. Example `ComboBox` QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ComboBox {
    id: dropDownList
    model: myModel
    textRole: "display"
    onActivated: {
        console.log("dropDownList Activated");
        console.log("Read Model Value: " + model.display);
    }
}
```

The console log I get is:

> ```
> qml: dropDownList Select Activated
> qml: Read Model Value: undefined
> ```

The `display` role values are shown correctly by the `ComboBox` itself.

I have also tried `model[index].display`, this gives

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined`

`model.get(index)` is not supported by `QAbstractListModel`, and doesn't have the role so it isn't suitable.

I believe this must be possible, as the `ComboBox` can display text from arbitrary roles.

Comment: I bet `myModel` is a context property, isn't it? If so, what about wrapping `data` with a `Q_INVOKABLE`/`SLOT` method and collected the desired role(s)?

Comment: BaCaRoZzo is correct. You need to add invokable methods to the model to access it directly. The `ComboBox`, unfortunately, does not expose the model to you :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use the undocumented property of the QuickControls 2 ComboBox `delegateModel`.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ComboBox {
    id: dropDownList
    model: myModel
    textRole: "display"
    onActivated: {
        console.log("dropDownList Activated");
        var currentItem = delegateModel.items.get(currentIndex)
        console.log("Read Model Value: " + currentItem.model.display);
    }
}
```

The items returned are javascript objects, not QtObjects so you cannot use the object returned by `delegateModel.items.get()` in bindings as it has no Qml properties.

Although this property is not documented it is mentioned in the [Customizing ComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox) example when setting the model used for the customized popup.

```
contentItem: ListView {
    clip: true
    implicitHeight: contentHeight
    model: control.popup.visible ? control.delegateModel : null
    currentIndex: control.highlightedIndex

    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
}
```